# WPF Modern UI - DialogResult with Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

My question is related to the **Modern UI** template for WPF Desktop applications.
My goal is to create a `DialogResult` with an icon image.

```cs
ModernDialog Dialog = new ModernDialog();
Dialog.Title = "DIALOG EXAMPLE";
Dialog.Buttons = new Button[] { Dialog.OkButton, Dialog.CancelButton};
Dialog.Content = "Testing a new DialogResult";
Dialog.ShowDialog();
//Dialog.Icon = ???;
```

The code above will create the following `DialogResult` window:

[image]

I am looking for something similar to the `MessageBoxImage` value:

[image]

I must use the `DialogResult` to fit the content with my **Modern UI** interface... any ideas on how insert an image file/SVG ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Icon` property is used to set the image of the window in the taskbar it isn't meant for that, to achieve what you are looking for you need to

- add a new ModernDialog page, that should be easy since you are using the VS modern UI template

[image: MessageDialog]

- Customize the `messageDialog` through its xaml and make it looks the way that you want

  ```
  <mui:ModernDialog x:Class="ModernUIApp1.ModernDialogMessage"                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
            Title="DIALOG EXAMPLE" >
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Image Source="imageIcon.jpg" Width="40"></Image>
      <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Text="Testing a new DialogResult"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
  </mui:ModernDialog>
  ```
- show it when needed

  ```
   var msg = new ModernDialogMessage();
   msg.ShowDialog();
  ```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you mate.